# Issue in nested for loops : How to speed up nested for loops

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to generate several combination of values that will be used as parameters in an equation. 
The problem ism, it is very computationally expensive and the machine gets hanged. When there are only 3-4 parameters, then for loop works alright and I get results within reasonable time. Otherwise, it just freezes!
Following, is the code. Can somebody please provide an efficient way to generate combinations of these numbers so that the whole process becomes faster and I don't have to wait for days to get the result.

UPDATE based on the reply in ANSWER1 : 
(Just a simple try)

```
>> a1 = 0.1;
>> b1 = 0.2;
>> a = a1 + [0 : 0.01 : 0.04]

a =

    0.1000    0.1100    0.1200    0.1300    0.1400

>> b = b1 + [0 : 0.01 : 0.04]

b =

    0.2000    0.2100    0.2200    0.2300    0.2400

>> aa, bb = ndgird(a, b)
Undefined function or variable 'aa'.
```

Few more Questions : 
(1) What is wrong in the way I did

(2) What does the term 0.04 mean?

(3) How do I specify the number of elements in each vector of parameters? In this example, only 5 values are generated.
thank you

Comment: @Schorsch:Please don't down vote this question, I am facing related problems with large equations. I don't know if there is any alternative way to tackle the problem

Comment: -1 for this sentence: *Can somebody please provide an efficient way [...]* - What is your effort in this, other than providing your problem? As Floris states in his answer: What do you *really* need to do? Maybe this is a problem for an optimizer instead of trying every single combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) to generate an n-dimensional grid for the parameter values.

E.g.

```
xx, yy = ndgrid([1,2,3],[0.1, 0.2,0.3])
```

for 2d, add more vectors for n-d.

**2D parameters array**

If you then need to have the parameters stored in a 2d array, you could do e.g.

```
[xx(:), yy(:),...]
```

**Specific values**

In your case you need to use the vectors

```
a = a1 + [0 : 0.01 : 0.04]
b = b2 + [0 : 0.01 : 0.04]
c = c3 - [0 : 0.01 : 0.04] 
...
```

or alternatively

```
a = a1 + linspace(0, 0.04, 5)
b = b2 + linspace(0, 0.04, 5)
c = c3 - linspace(0, 0.04, 5) 
...
```

and so on, such that each vector corresponds to the values you need to scan over. 
Then use

```
[aa, bb, cc, ...] = ndgrid(a, b, c,...)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but unfortunately I cannot follow how I can rectify my code with it. Could you please elaborate a bit? SInce I have 12 parameters so should I be doing x1, x2,till x12 = ndgrid([1,2,3],[0.1, 0.2,0.3]) and how do i include the increment of 0.01?

Comment: I went through the documentation but could not understand the terms in the signature ndgrid([1 2 3])

Comment: @SrishtiM: No the values I used were just examples; I updated my answer for your scenario

Comment: I just used the following piece (not my code in the question) so as to understand what ndgrid works and I got the following error "Undefined function or variable 'aa'. I have put up the error part in the  Question, could you kindly have a look? Also, what does the last term 0.04 mean? I  understand that the increment is 0.01 but what is 0.04 since I get 5 values in total for each vector.

Comment: I suggest that you generate the vectors with code like `a = linspace(0, 0.04, 5);` - this explicitly says "from `0` to `0.04`, with a total of `5` values". But `0:0.01:0.04` means "start at `0`, then keep adding `0.01` until you are greater than `0.04`. This gives `0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04` - a total of 5 values.

Comment: @Floris: Thanks for your suggestion (and your edit - too much time in python!)

Comment: @jmetz - you are welcome. Incidentally the Matlab editor suggests replacing `a1 + [0 : 0.01 : 0.04]` with `a1 + (0:0.01:0.04)` - in other words, using round rather than square brackets. There is a speed penalty involved - see http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/35676-why-not-use-square-brackets

Answer (score 2):

Some things to consider:

1) unless you pre-allocate the array, the growth of `stor_param` will be slow as matlab keeps having to find more space, copying data in the process. Use

```
stor_param=zeros(12,bigN);
```

Note that `bigN= 5^12;` which is about 244 Million...

2) You are looping all parameters over all possible values of `t` -this is another very large multiplier.

These two things together tell me that even efficient code will take quite some time; I recommend that you think about what you really need to do (when you have these 4E10 results what will you do with them?...)

The fastest solution is the one that does the least work. Right now your "algorithm" is brute force...

**edit** I am pretty sure that you are trying to find an optimum of some sort. If that is indeed the case, there are very efficient methods built in to Matlab to make that possible.  Most of these are in the optimization toolbox; there are many examples online on how to use these functions. They include various methods for adding constraints - either boundary constraints (parameters no larger than `xx` or smaller than `yy`), or linked constraints (`aa < 2*bb`). Using these types of techniques will allow you to find a good combination of parameters much more easily than your current approach. Because even with `ndgrid`, you are evaluating your function many, many times...

Comment: +1 for suspecting an [xy-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and elaborating on the optimization approach.